How to serve dynamic status information from a sensor via ROS node
I'm learning how to code a C++ driver for ROS2 (Humble, at the moment) to access a custom measuring device. Beside continuous measurement data streams and parameters for static configuration, the device provides status variables that need to be actively queried if you want up-to-date information.
It seemed natural to me that those variables could be presented by the driver in the form of ROS parameters, so one could ros2 param get node status to get status from node, but I don't see any way to link a callback that retrieves the most recent value from the sensor whenever someone asks for it. using the node's get_parameters service. So status value is always what had been stored there at some time in the past.
So "parameters" are not the right idea? I probably have to provide a separate service for retrieval of such variables? A service that causes the request to the device and returns the device's response? Or did I miss some mechanism that could be linked to the get_parameters service implementation?
Kolja
